# Не могу удалить из mysql отдельный элемент ячейки

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Делаю так в phpMyAdmin, но данные не удаляются:

```
DELETE FROM images_big WHERE filename = '22.jpg'
```

Как сделать, чтобы данные удалялись в определенном месте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SQL позволяет оперировать строками. Удалить можно только всю запись целиком. Вам надо либо самом обновить содержимое поля с помощью update. Либо, что гораздо лучше, переделать структуру БД и вынести списки файлов в отдельную таблицу, что бы каждый файл лежал отдельной записью. А использование любых списков через запятую, как у вас сейчас вызывает массу проблем, ибо SQL просто не предназначен для работы такими данными

Comment: Не стал бы обобщать, но в целом верно, - а так, есть исключения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, лучше разделить содержимое filename, добавив его в отдельно созданную таблицу, где будет связь по u_login, и тогда уже удалять.

Тогда не придется удалять целую запись, содержащую что-то еще, кроме "22.jpg" в "filename".

P.S. Либо удалять с помощью LIKE:

```
DELETE FROM images_big WHERE filename LIKE '22.jpg%'
```

Comment: сори удалил всю строку, а не отдельный элемент

Comment: Вот чтобы такого не было, и надо создать отдельную таблицу для файлов, а там уже хранить все файлы отдельно с привязкой, и лучше, чтобы привязкой служила 3 таблица, как обычно и делается: это правильная архитектура.

Comment: Отдельный же элемент удалить с помощью SQL довольно проблематично. Как правильно написал @Mike в комментарии выше, нужно вначале считывать содержимое filename, потом же делать UPDATE, исключая оттуда конкретный файл. Лучше не идти этим путем от слова совсем.